# What was "the day" Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai disagreed?

Tags: fast-days, shulchan-aruch, beis-shammai, beis-hillel

The [Shulchan Aruch OC (580:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.580.2?lang=bi&with=Kaf%20HaChayim&lang2=en) codifies the list of sad days some have the custom to fast for, which includes at the end:

> בט' בו נחלקו בית שמאי ובית הלל - The ninth of Adar is when Beis
> Shammai and Beis Hillel disagreed.

What does this refer to? (Is there one specific day when they disagreed on everything, the first day they argued, etc.?)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.1.4

Comment: cool https://www.9adar.org/about/what-is-9adar/

Comment: @DoubleAA Great find! 3,000 talmidim may have been killed!? How has this never been made into a landmark speech during Adar? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36640/is-the-story-about-members-of-beis-shammai-killing-members-of-beis-hillel-true?rq=1

Comment: Probably most people thought it was not p'shat.